# Finding all nodes without any text node

Tags: .net, xpath

With XPath (.NET), I'm trying to select all nodes that don't contain any text node.

Given this document:

```
<root>
  <node1>
    <node1a>Node 1A</node1a>
  </node1>
  <node2>Node 2</node2>
  <node3>
    <node3a>Node 3A</node3a>
    <node3b></node3b>
  </node3>
  <node4></node4>
  <node5>
    <node5A></node5A>
  </node5>
</root>
```

I'm tyring to get the nodes:

```
<node3b></node3b>

<node4></node4>

<node5>
  <node5A></node5A>
</node5>
```

Note that overlapping subtrees are merged, so node5A should not be returned separately.

I would expect this to pull the trick, but for some reason (which is probably obvious when someone points it out) it doesn't:

```
//*[count(//text()) = 0]
```

Note: I'm using [XPath tester](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) to try things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your result example is really what you want (which is not totally in accordance with statement in the title) the suggestions above

```
//*[count(.//text()) = 0]
```

or the preferred way

```
//*[not(.//text())]
```

Doesn't work as the result is not what you expected

```
<node3b />
<node4 />
<node5>
  <node5A />
</node5>
<node5A /> <!-- this node is not present in your example -->
```

If what you want is all subtrees without any text node not included in other resulting subtrees the solution is this one

```
//*[not(.//text())][not(ancestor::*[not(.//text())])]
```

The second predicate remove from the result all the nodes which has at least one ancestor already included in the result

Comment: Nice nitpicking there ;) I do need subtrees merged, so I edited the question.

Answer (score 2):

Arg... and just when posting, the solution crops up:

```
//*[count(.//text()) = 0]
```

Explanation: the condition `count(//text()) = 0` counts all text nodes from the root, which is always greater than zero. To count from the current node, I needed to prefix the dot: `count(.//text()) = 0`

Note that @jvverde correctly remarks that nodes can occur multiple times in the result set. So this expression is not an exact match for the conditions I mention, as node5A is in there twice:

```
<node3b></node3b>

<node4></node4>

<node5>
  <node5A></node5A>
</node5>

<node5A></node5A>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `//*[.='']` as far as empty element should have empty string value.

Comment: This needs to calculate the data string first and can be much more expensive than counting text nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the more simple and readable

```
//*[not(.//text())]
```

or replace `not(...)` by `empty(...)` if you prefer.

Both are already optimized, so even simple XPath implementations should be able to implement them in a "fail-fast" manner (found one text node, evaluate predicate to false).

Comment: I did some experimenting with `not` before I realized where the culprit in my expression was. I'll try out your suggestion, so you might get the reward ;)